# R: Remove the rows in domain 'condition' within 270 days before and after the date of rows in domain 'procedure'

Tags: r, date, data-cleaning

I have a question regarding how to clean a dataset using R.

Now I have a dataset that looks like this:

Columns: ID, date, domain;

domain includes: procedure, condition

date is YYYY-MM-DD;

```r
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5)

date <- c('2018-06-29','2018-08-29','2018-08-29','2020-12-11','2020-12-12','2021-01-21','2021-12-21','2020-11-29','2019-07-12','2018-05-13','2021-06-08','2017-11-14','2018-07-15','2019-01-15','2019-02-19','2021-11-09','2021-11-10','2021-10-09','2021-07-13','2022-12-01')

domain <- c('condition','condition','procedure','condition','procedure','condition','condition','procedure','condition','procedure','procedure','procedure','condition','procedure','condition','procedure','condition','condition','condition','condition')

df <- data.frame(ID, date, domain)
```

Example dateset:

```r
> df
   ID       date    domain
1   1 2018-06-29 condition
2   1 2018-08-29 condition
3   1 2018-08-29 procedure
4   2 2020-12-11 condition
5   2 2020-12-12 procedure
6   2 2021-01-21 condition
7   2 2021-12-21 condition
8   3 2020-11-29 procedure
9   4 2019-07-12 condition
10  4 2018-05-13 procedure
11  4 2021-06-08 procedure
12  5 2017-11-14 procedure
13  5 2018-07-15 condition
14  5 2019-01-15 procedure
15  5 2019-02-19 condition
16  5 2021-11-09 procedure
17  5 2021-11-10 condition
18  5 2021-10-09 condition
19  5 2021-07-13 condition
20  5 2022-12-01 condition
```

I would like to remove all the rows in domain 'condition' within 270 days before and after a certain row in domain 'procedure' for each ID.

In other words, for each ID, use the rows in domain 'procedure' as anchors, remove all the rows in domain 'condition' within 270 days before and after the anchors. That is, for each ID, remove the rows in domain 'condition' within the range: date of procedure ± 270 days

For example, the desired output would be:

```r
   ID date      domain      decision
1   1 2018-06-29 condition  drop
2   1 2018-08-29 condition  drop
3   1 2018-08-29 procedure  keep

4   2 2020-12-11 condition  drop
5   2 2020-12-12 procedure  keep
6   2 2021-01-21 condition  drop
7   2 2021-12-21 condition  keep

8   3 2020-11-29 procedure  keep

9   4 2019-07-12 condition  keep
10  4 2018-05-13 procedure  keep
11  4 2021-06-08 procedure  keep

12  5 2017-11-14 procedure  keep
13  5 2018-07-15 condition  drop
14  5 2019-01-15 procedure  keep
15  5 2019-02-19 condition  drop
16  5 2021-11-09 procedure  keep
17  5 2021-11-10 condition  drop
18  5 2021-10-09 condition  drop
19  5 2021-07-13 condition  drop
20  5 2022-12-01 condition  keep
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `cbind` here is producing a `matrix`, not a `data.frame` as you appear to be depicting.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the 'date' to `Date` (with `as.Date`), then grouped by 'ID', get the difference between 'date' and 'date' where `domain` is 'procedure', check if the `abs`olute value is greater than or equal to 270 or (`|`) if the domain is "procedure"

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 <- df %>%
   mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(decision = case_when(map(date[domain== "procedure"], 
   ~abs(as.numeric(difftime(date, .x, units = "days"))) >= 
     270|domain == "procedure" ) %>% 
       reduce(`&`) ~ "keep", TRUE ~ "drop")) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
> df1
# A tibble: 20 × 4
      ID date       domain    decision
   <dbl> <date>     <chr>     <chr>   
 1     1 2018-06-29 condition drop    
 2     1 2018-08-29 condition drop    
 3     1 2018-08-29 procedure keep    
 4     2 2020-12-11 condition drop    
 5     2 2020-12-12 procedure keep    
 6     2 2021-01-21 condition drop    
 7     2 2021-12-21 condition keep    
 8     3 2020-11-29 procedure keep    
 9     4 2019-07-12 condition keep    
10     4 2018-05-13 procedure keep    
11     4 2021-06-08 procedure keep    
12     5 2017-11-14 procedure keep    
13     5 2018-07-15 condition drop    
14     5 2019-01-15 procedure keep    
15     5 2019-02-19 condition drop    
16     5 2021-11-09 procedure keep    
17     5 2021-11-10 condition drop    
18     5 2021-10-09 condition drop    
19     5 2021-07-13 condition drop    
20     5 2022-12-01 condition keep
```

NOTE: This creates a column in original data as 'decision'.  Instead if we want to remove the rows, use `filter` on the logical output

```
df1 <- df %>%
   mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   filter(map(date[domain== "procedure"], 
   ~abs(as.numeric(difftime(date, .x, units = "days"))) >= 
     270|domain == "procedure" ) %>% 
       reduce(`&`) ) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
> df1
# A tibble: 11 × 3
      ID date       domain   
   <dbl> <date>     <chr>    
 1     1 2018-08-29 procedure
 2     2 2020-12-12 procedure
 3     2 2021-12-21 condition
 4     3 2020-11-29 procedure
 5     4 2019-07-12 condition
 6     4 2018-05-13 procedure
 7     4 2021-06-08 procedure
 8     5 2017-11-14 procedure
 9     5 2019-01-15 procedure
10     5 2021-11-09 procedure
11     5 2022-12-01 condition
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. What an expert you are!

Comment: May I ask in 'date[domain == "procedure"][1]', what does [1] do?

Comment: @KingAwake For most IDs, there is a single 'procedure'.  if there are none, then the output after subset returns `character(0)`, With `[1]`, it coerces to `NA` (or else we have to use `if/else` condition for such cases

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again. I found that if the ID is with more than 1 record of procedure, then the condition records around the 2nd and 3rd procedures will not be removed. Can I ask how to solve this?

Comment: @KingAwake From your input dataset for IDs 4 and 5, there are multiple 'procedure'.  It is not clear which one of them should be used to compare against the 'condition'.  Are you looking to compare the 'condition' against all of the 'procedure' and if it is all TRUE, only the 'keep'?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry for the deficiency with the sample dataset! For each ID, I would like to remove those conditions which lie between, (procedure-270 and procedure+270), for any procedure for the same ID, no matter the number of the procedures. The original dataset was created as for each ID, neighbor procedures are apart from each other for at least 270 days. Besides, every ID has at least one procedure record in the original dataset.

Comment: Please update your data with a more reproducible example

Comment: I have updated the sample dataset, please take a look when you have time. Thank you.

Comment: @KingAwake please check the update.  Also, please don't specify thank you comments here.  There is a SO guideline about what to do if you find the answer solves your problem